# May a column from a python pandas dataframe be a list or set or...?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

All is in the title : May a column from a python pandas dataframe be a list or ensemble or tuple or ... ?

```
 import pandas as pd

    lnks = [ ( 'a' , 'b') , ( 'b' , 'c') , ( 'c' , 'a' ) , ('b' , 'd' ) , ( 'd' , 'a' ) ]

    lbls = [ 'x' , 'y']

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records( lnks , columns = lbls )
```

Trying to build a new column z of type ensemble from columns x and y row values :

```
df[ 'z' ] =  { df[ 'x' ] , df[ 'y' ] }
```

I get the following error code :

TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hash

I would like to obtain a dataframe containing :

```
x y z

'a' 'b' { 'a  , 'b' }
'b' 'c' { 'b' , 'c' }
'c' 'a' { 'c' , 'a' }
...
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tuples use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for process by rows:

```
df[ 'z' ] =  df.apply(lambda x: (x[ 'x' ] , x[ 'y' ]), axis=1)
print (df)
   x  y       z
0  a  b  (a, b)
1  b  c  (b, c)
2  c  a  (c, a)
3  b  d  (b, d)
4  d  a  (d, a)
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
lnks = [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('b', 'd'), ('d', 'a')]
lbls = ['x', 'y']

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lnks, columns=lbls)

df['z'] = df.apply(lambda r: ( r.x, r.y ), axis=1) #if you want a tuple
```

or

```
df['z'] = df.apply(lambda r: [r.x, r.y ], axis=1)  #if you want a list
print(df)
```

Comment: hi, what i need is a set object for each values of the new z column. Thanks anyway.